# How to show image from compressed representation (RNN)?

Tags: image, neural-network, runtime-error, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am learning RNN with pytorch from this github.

[Pytorch RNN Tutorial](https://github.com/yunjey/pytorch-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/02-intermediate/recurrent_neural_network/main.py)

I'm a little bit confused, because the code didn't show result of the training. Only show the accuracy. Now I want to show image that output from model.

I try to save image from output, but the result I get is a compressed representation (below is the image I got from output of the model)

[image: compressed representation]

```
# Train the model
total_step = len(train_loader)
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        images = images.reshape(-1, sequence_length, input_size).to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        # Backward and optimize
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if (i+1) % 100 == 0:
            print ('Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}' 
                    .format(epoch+1, num_epochs, i+1, total_step, loss.item()))
```

I am trying to show the image of the output by adding this code

```
plt.imshow(outputs.reshape(28, 28))
```

But I got this error

```
RuntimeError: shape '[28, 28]' is invalid for input of size 1000
```

So, I assume that the output is 1000 size. but I want it to show as a mnist image (784 size (28*28)).

Comment: Well, if your image has 1,000 pixels, I guess it must be 31.62 pixels square, or 40x25, or 50x20...

Comment: i am using MNIST dataset. So i think to show the image it should be 28*28.
But some how after it went though the model it turn to 1000 pixel

Comment: `outputs` variable contains the logits predicted by the model, it is not an image you can show. You can print the predicted label or show the input image, but visualizing the output is more complicated. 

1000 comes from `batch size x number of classes` (100 x 10), remember, you have to visualize each image separately. Also, consider visualizing the output of the RNN instead of the logits, but again, since the output will be a vector and not a matrix, I doubt that help you in any way.